# Removing characters from STDIN path location

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program that asks a user for the file location of the input for the program.
Instead of having the user type out the entire location, is it possible to have them simply drag the file from its location to the command line? When I attempt this, it places `'` around the file location. 
Could you remove the `'` character from the STDIN before the program attempts to open the file? I'm getting the feeling that this is an operating system function rather than perl.

Comment: replace `/'(.+)'/` with `/\1/` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove single quotes from a string using

```
$string =~ s/'//g;
```

or, slightly more efficiently

```
$string =~ tr/'//d;
```

But have you considered passing the file name on the command line, so that you run your Perl program using

```
perl myprogram.pl myfile
```

That way the quotes are correct, and there is no need to open the file in the program. You can just write

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I had considered passing the file name on the command line. I may just do that instead of assuming the user will know what to do.